# Updating TABLE columns appropriately with default values

Tags: sql-server, default

Lets say i have a table 'xyz' with columns a, b, c, d, e and i find out that columns are randomly empty in the table. Now i have to scan through the table find out where the columns are empty and update the columns with default values (example a with 'a', b with 'b', c with 'c' ...) while leaving the other columns in the row unaltered. How can that be done?

I have created the following procedure but it doesn't augur well to me:

```
 create procedure SP_DEFAULTS as
 update xyz set a= 'a',
b= 'b',
c= 'c'
d= 'd',
e= 'e' 

where (a='' 
or b='' 
or c='' 
or d='' 
or e=''
)
```

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 4):

Do not run your SQL. You'll update the wrong stuff.

```
update xyz
set
   a=CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(ISNULL(a,''))='' THEN 'a'
        ELSE a
     END,
   b=CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(ISNULL(b,''))='' THEN 'b'
        ELSE b
     END,
   c=CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(ISNULL(c,''))='' THEN 'c'
        ELSE c
     END,
   d=CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(ISNULL(d,''))='' THEN 'a'
        ELSE d
     END,
   e=CASE
        WHEN LTRIM(ISNULL(e,''))='' THEN 'a'
        ELSE e
     END
WHERE
(
        LTRIM(ISNULL(a,''))='' 
    OR  LTRIM(ISNULL(b,''))='' 
    OR  LTRIM(ISNULL(c,''))='' 
    OR  LTRIM(ISNULL(d,''))='' 
    OR  LTRIM(ISNULL(e,''))='' 
)
```

Comment: That is a good idea. Why didnt I think of that :P? Must be too early in the morning.

Comment: Agree with the idea but I think you don't need `LTRIM`. Also, the expressions in the SET clause could be simpler: `a = ISNULL(NULLIF(a, ''), 'a')`.

Comment: I added the trim with the idea that this would cover nulls, empty strings, and strings comprised of spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Currently what you have will update the entire row when one of the fields is empty. You will have to do something more like this, so that you can only update that field when it is empty. Also after you have completed the SP, you should set defaults on the table for each field so that this wont ever happen again.

```
UPDATE xyz 
SET    a = 'a'
WHERE  a = ''

UPDATE xyz 
SET    b = 'b'
WHERE  b = ''

UPDATE xyz 
SET    c = 'c'
WHERE  c = ''

UPDATE xyz 
SET    d = 'd'
WHERE  d = ''

UPDATE xyz 
SET    e = 'e'
WHERE  e = ''
```

Comment: @user653622 : This is the simplest approach, but if you'll ever need the fields to be dynamic, it will be a whole lot more complicated than this; we'll be using dynamic SQL and we may have to access system tables..

Answer (score 2):

```
update xyz set 
 a=coalesce(a,'a'), 
 b=coalesce(b,'b'), 
 c=coalesce(c,'c'),
 d=coalesce(d,'d')
```

Coalesce returns teh first non-null value in a series of values/variables.  so if field a is null, then it returns the string 'a'

I'd put a where clause on it using a pk and evalalute if this does what you want then remove the where clause.  It updates every value on every field, but where information already exists, it uses that information.